# Generate graph report from an already existing .jtl file

Tags: graph, jmeter

I'm trying to generate graphs from my already existing .jtl file whose location is as follows:

```
D:\Codeaccess\SPOJ_Jmeter_APIS_Difficult\Test_Results\CPP\CPPResults.jtl
```

I want to store it in the same folder i.e.

D:\Codeaccess\SPOJ_Jmeter_APIS_Difficult\Test_Results\CPP with some name as graphResults.jtl

How do i do the same with report dashboard?I have followed the [link](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) but not sure how it is to be done using the properties file and how to access it.

looking forward to some good help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do we need to mention in user.properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Generation from an existing sample CSV log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) section it can be done as follows:

```
jmeter -g D:\Codeaccess\SPOJ_Jmeter_APIS_Difficult\Test_Results\CPP\CPPResults.jtl -o D:\Codeaccess\SPOJ_Jmeter_APIS_Difficult\Test_Results\CPP\graphResults.jtl
```

this command will pick up all the actual [JMeter properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) (jmeter.properties, user.properties, reportgenerator.properties) and apply them to the dashboard

Comment: Hi @Dmitri i used the following command in the bin folder of jmeter cmd prompt, jmeter -g D:\Codeaccess\SPOJ_Jmeter_APIS_Difficult\Test_Results\CPP\CPPResults.jtl -o D:\Codeaccess\SPOJ_Jmeter_APIS_Difficult\Test_Results\CPP\HTML_ResultsCPP yet my command prompt does not show anything. the file size of jtl file is 3,59,744 KB. what could be the possible reason to it? Is it related to user.properties file, jmeter.properties file or what?

Comment: I cannot state anything meaningful unless i see the command output and the contents of [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)

Comment: my command prompt shows the following: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid1720.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [1835856344 bytes in 11.285 secs]
An error occurred: Java heap space
errorlevel=1

Comment: You need to increase [JVM Heap](https://www.azul.com/resources/azul-technology/what-is-java-heap-size/) size allocated to JMeter, try going for 80% of your total available RAM and adjust up or down according to the size of your .jtl file and JMeter heap consumption. Like `set HEAP=8G && jmeter -g ....`. More information: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use UI to generate dashboard from jtl file, [menu item](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_gui) Tools → Generate HTML report
[image]

Comment: Alright and is there any way to download this html report?

Comment: @Radhika write the output directory

Comment: The above report is taking more than 5 minutes and still not downloaded. As suggested in the link above :If report generation takes more than two minutes, adjust the property generate_report_ui.generation_timeout. Where do i set this property???

Comment: @Radhika jmeter.properties (or user.properties) add row with generate_report_ui.generation_timeout=360000 (6 minutes)

Comment: I have changed the properties in jmeter.properties but still no change. It was already there in jmeter.properties file. It takes a lot of time

Comment: @Radhika if it's exists with leading `#` sign it's ignored

Comment: yes it was with a #sign in jmeter.properties file. So now should I import user.properties file or jmeter.properties file in my html report tools menu?

Comment: I have tried jmeter -g D:\Codeaccess\SPOJ_Jmeter_APIS_Difficult\Test_Results\CPP\CPPResults.jtl -o D:\Codeaccess\SPOJ_Jmeter_APIS_Difficult\Test_Results\CPP\HTML_ResultsCPP command in the command prompt as well but it is taking a lot of time